# Udoo motion sensors

Tags: arduino

I'm building a home alarm system and I have 2 motion sensors. The problem is that only one of the sensors works and I don't know why.

The board is connected to the 12V power supply. The *+* connections on the sensors are connected to the VIN on the board. The ground is the same and 2 separate pins *s* for input from the sensors.

```cpp
int senz = 3;
int senz1 = 4;
int led = 5;
int led1 = 6;
int val = 0;
int val1 = 0;
void stetup
{
    pinMode(senz, INPUT);

    pinMode(senz1, INPUT);

    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop
{
    val = digitalRead(senz);
    if (val == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        Serial.println("motion");
    }
    if (val == LOW) {
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        Serial.println("no motion");
    }
    val1 = digitalRead(senz1);
    if (val1 == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
        Serial.println("motion");
    }
    if (val1 == LOW) {
        digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
        Serial.println("no motion");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post proper code without typos. And you are not writing to `led1` both inputs write to `led`, while the messages do not say *which* sensor.

Comment: Indentation/formatting.......

Answer (score 0):

In case, when there are more than two sensors it's better to use I2C protocol. I have used [3 axis Accelerometer](https://store.ncd.io/product/mxc6232xm-low-power-%C2%B12g-dual-axis-accelerometer-i2c-mini-module/) for the same purpose. This module also offers I2C compatibility and we can use wire library to read the data from these sensors.